# How to center a UIView based on the visible part of another view?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm working on an iOS app in Swift which contains an UIScrollView. The scrollview is "infinite", new elements (subclassed UIViews) are automatically generated on both sides as needed. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/StreetScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011102) for the example by Apple I based this on.

The view hierarchy:

```
UIScrollView
|- viewContainer (UIView containing all the elements in the scrollview)
   |- A 
   |  |- UILabel(hi)
   |
   |- B
   |  |- UILabel(hello)
   |
   |- C
   |  |- UILabel(bonjour)
   |
   |- D
   |  |- UILabel(ciao)
   |
   |- E
   |  |- UILabel(greetings)
```

The subviews A-E each contain a UILabel with some text. As the scrollview moves horizontally, new subviews (F, G, etc) are automatically created.

I'm trying to center the UILabels based on the *visible* part (the part that the user can actually see) of the elements.

[image: Explanation]

See the image above:

- (1) Currently elements A, B and C are visible to the user.
- (1) Element B is fully visible, it's label is exactly center.
- (1) However, element C is not fully visible, so it's label moves to the left to make as much of the text visible as possible.
- (2) When the user scrolls the scrollview to the left, new elements become visible.
- (2) As a larger part of element C becomes more visible, more of it's text is displayed. As soon as the entire element is visible, the text centers automatically.
- (3?) If the user would scroll further, and element C would start to drop off the screen on the left side, the label should move to the right side so as to stay visible as long as possible.

All this would happen continuously during scrolling.

**Now for the question:**
How can I make the labels behave in the fashion described above? I have so far been experimenting with overriding `layoutSubViews` in the elements (A-E). However I have not even been able to extract the part of the elements that is visible to the user. `layer.visibleRect` seems to give me the entire rectangle, even the portions that are currently offscreen.

Any help or pointers are appreciated!

Comment: to get the visible rectangle did you try `CGRect visibleRect = CGRectIntersection(self.frame, superview.bounds);`

Comment: @Aladin, yes I did. But it just gives the full width of the elements, not the size that is visible. There is a complicating factor which I should have mentioned before: the `UIScrollView.contentSize.width` is larger (5000) than the screen. This is to make the infinite scrolling trick work properly. Since this somehow affects the bounds, the bounds are much larger than the visible part of the screen.